# bash-store variable value into JSON file

Tags: json, bash

i have JSON file

```
{
    "fields":
    {
        "project":
        {
            "key": "TECH"
        },
        "parent":
        {
            "key": "TECH-456"
        },
        "summary": "Sub-task of TEST-456",
        "description": "Don't forget to do this too.",
        "issuetype":
        {
            "id": "5"
        }
    }
}
```

i want output of  parent='aaaaa' to put into

```
"parent":
    {
     "key": "variable value=$parent"
    },
```

and output of project='bbbb'

put into

```
"project":
 {
 "key": variable value=$project
 },
```

i'm trying using jq like 
jq -n --arg $ja '.fields.project.key=$ja' my.json but getting error

Comment: You don't have `.issues` array in the JSON input you show. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lot trial & errors finally got it:

```
project=`jq -r '.issues[0] | .key' 1.json`
parent=`jq -r '.issues[0] | .fields.project.key' 1.json`
cat my.json | jq --arg project "$project" '.fields.project.key=$project' | jq --arg parent "$parent" '.fields.parent.key=$parent'>aa.json
```